# Operator+ overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, concatenation, addition

Okay I am very new to operator overloading and I have to execute this function in an object oriented program, but I definitely need help. Here are the instructions:

> The MyString object should contain a Print() method that prints the
>   string
>
> The MyString object should contain a Length() method that reports the
>   length of the string
>
> The MyString object should contain a default constructor that sets the
>   inital string to the value of "Hello World".
>
> The MyString object should contain an alternate constructor that
>   allows for setting of the inital value of the string.
>
> The MyString object should overload the following operators:
>
> - Parenthesis operators should be overloaded to replace the Set and Get functions of your previous assignment. Note that both instances
>     should issue exit(1) upon violation of the string array bounaries.
> - Assignment operator (=) which will copy the source string into the destination string. Note that size of the destination needs to be
>     adjusted to be the same as the source.
> - Logical comparison operator (==) that returns true iff the two strings are identical in size and contents.
> - Negated logical comparison operator (!=) that returns boolean negation of 2.
> - **Addition operator (+) that concatenates two strings**
> - Addition/Assigment operator (+=) used in the following fashion: String1 += String2 to operate as String1 = String1 + String2
> - **Both addition (+) and assignment (=) operators need to be capable of cascaded operations. This means String3 = String1 +
>     String2, or String1 = String2 = String3 should work.**

Here is my code in the .cpp file:

```
MyString::MyString()
{
       char temp[] = "Hello World";

       int counter(0);
        while(temp[counter] != '\0') {
              counter++;
       }
       Size = counter;
        String = new char [Size];
        for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
            String[i] = temp[i];

}

MyString::MyString(char *message)

{
      int counter(0);
       while(message[counter] != '\0') {
            counter++;
        }
       Size = counter;
      String = new char [Size];
      for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
             String[i] = message[i];
 }

 MyString::~MyString()
 {
      delete [] String;
 }

 int MyString::Length()
 {
       int counter(0);

       while(String[counter] != '\0')
       {
             counter ++;
        }

       return (counter);
  }

**const MyString operator +(const MyString& one, const MyString& two)
{
       MyString String1;
       return String1;
 }**



MyString& MyString::operator()(const int index, const char b)
{
       if(String[index] == '\0')
       {
               exit(1);
       }
       else
       {
         String[index] = b;
       }


 }

MyString& MyString::operator=(const MyString& rhs)
{

        Size = rhs.Size;
        counter = rhs.counter;

        delete [] String;
        String = new char[Size];


        for(int i = 0; i < counter+1 ; i++)
       {
               String[i] = rhs.String[i];
       }
       return *this;

 }

 bool MyString::operator==(const MyString& one)
 {
       if(one.Length() == two.Length())
       {
              for(int i = 0; i < one.Length()+1; i++)
              {
                      if(one[i] == two[i])
                            return true;
              }
       }
       else
             return false;
 }

 MyString& MyString::operator()(const int i)
 {

        if( String[i] == '\0')
        {
              exit(1);
        }
        else
       {

            return String[i];

       }
 }

void MyString::Print()
{
       for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
               cout << String[i];
       cout << endl;

}
```

Here is my code in the main file:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

 MyString String1;             //Test of default constructor. Use "Hello world"
 MyString String2 ("Two strings are not equal");       //Test of alternate constructor
 MyString String3 ("Two strings are equal");
 MyString String4 (String1);

 cout << "*************Test of values*************" << endl;
 String1.Print ();
 String2.Print ();
 String3.Print ();

 cout << "*************Test of Length*************" << endl;
 cout << String1.Length () << " ";
 cout << String2.Length () << " ";
 cout << String3.Length () << endl;

 cout << "*************Test of Set*************" << endl;
 String1 (0, 'J');
 String1.Print ();

 cout << "*************Test of Copy*************" << endl;
 String1.Print ();
 cout << endl;
 String3.Print ();
 cout << endl;
 String3.Copy (String1);       //String1 should be copied into String3
 String1.Print ();
 cout << endl;
 String3.Print ();
 cout << endl;

 cout << "*************Test of Get*************" << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < String1.Length (); i++)   //The last character should exit the    program
   {
      cout << String1 (i) << " ";
   }
  }
   cout << endl;

   if (String1 == String4)
   {
      String3.Print ();
   }
   else
   {
     String4.Print ();
   }

   if (String1 != String4)
   {
      String3.Print ();
   }
   else
   {
      String4.Print ();
    }

   String1 = String2 = String3;
   String1.Print ();
   String2.Print ();
   String3.Print ();


   String1 = String2 + String3 + String4;
   String1.Print ();

   String2 += String3;
   String2.Print ();

   return 0;

 }
```

The main.cpp file cannot change but the other .cpp file has to compile and run along with that file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to put the declaration of the operator in a header, but the problem you have is that you are using `operator+` for your string inside the `operator+` for your string

```
const MyString operator +(const MyString& one, const MyString& two) {
        MyString String1 = one + two; // this calls operator+, which calls operator+, which calls...
        return String1;
}
```

Also, since you are returning a `MyString` by value, you shouldn't return by `const`:

```
MyString operator +(const MyString& one, const MyString& two) {
        MyString String1;
        // do something with the data of one and two and put it in String1
        return String1;
}
```

Finally, if your operator needs to access non-public data of `MyString`, you should declare it as a friend of your `MyString` class.

```
class MyString {

// as before

friend MyString operator+(const Mytring& rhs, const MyString& lhs);

};
```

Comment: You and I were writing answers at the same time, but yours is better and covers all the ground mine covers.  Deleting mine now.  Thanks.  +1

Comment: I'm trying to concatenate two strings but I'm confused on how I should do that without actually using the +.

Comment: @user1363061 it really depends on the specifics of your `MyString` class.Maybe you can give some more details?

Comment: Any other tips or hints you could give me would be helpful!

Comment: It looks like what you need to do is to take set the temporary `String1`'s `String` member variable to a concatenation of `one.String` and `two.String`. I would just use `std::string`, but maybe you aren't allowed to do that?

Comment: I don't believe I can. When concatenating the one.String and two.String would you not still be able to use +? i.e. String1 = one.String + two.String? That's the only way I can think of that working, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @user1363061 I am assuming your `String` is a `char` array. You can't just add them together with `+`. So a search for "concatenating char array".